# how to move sqlite database which have already data from computer to mobile device?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i dont know how ask my query but i m try to understand my problem to you
i am making an competition `MCQ application` and i m inserted question, four choice option and answer into `Sqlite database`.
this application properly work on my pc `emulator` every question answer and choice fatch one by one on `emulator`
but when i run its apk on `mobile` why is my database empty ?
my question, answer and choice option data not show in `mobile` so what i do ?
how to move my already inserted data into mobile by apk ?
i think you under stand my problem 
so plz sir help me and solve my problem 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once and my problem was that the database already existed on the device but was an old version and did not have my most recent tables.

You can try deleting the database on the device. Thats not as easy as on the emulator so I used this code.

```
    File file = getDatabasePath("mydatabase.db");    
    if(file.exists()){
        file.delete();
    }

    file = getDatabasePath("mydatabase.db-journal");
    if(file.exists()){
        file.delete();
    }
```

Then wehn you try and use the database again it will be created.

Good luck